# Storing Configuration parameter in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am putting this question as a discussion, hoping to get a answer.
I am planning to add some configuration variable in the system. That can be used for various scenario. May be to configure some FTP connection or JDBC connection or a XML service parameter.

This may be something like configuring a Global Variable (TIBCO) or a Property file (Java).I was thinking of adding a CustomRecord. But I am not sure if it is a good option. Or can we do a caching or this record type. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Look into script parameters. You can add script parameters to your scripts, they are basically fields that store some value that you can access within your script.

If you want to access the parameter from any script you can make it a 
company parameter and you would set it by going into:

Setup>Company>General Preferences> Custom Preferences

You could also go with the custom record route or even saving/loading a JSON object in a file in the filing cabinet.

Comment: Ok... If I go for a option of JSON object or record type then is it possible to do a caching ? Some thing like session ? I just read the data from JSON/Record once and I fetch those value when ever i required in my SS ?

Comment: Yeah, I have had success using file cabinet files for caching. They are really useful.

Comment: Assume that I have a written some SS for reading and storing the value of the config key in the cache. then how do we invoke the SS ? Is it that we run the SS manually or we can any other mechanism.

Comment: You can run the SS manually or on a scheduled script, it's up to you.

Comment: I am able to do the caching work. Its also accessible for other users. But my problem is its getting nullified after some time. Do you have any idea how I can keep this alive always ?

Comment: No idea, I have never had issues with my files getting nullified. Maybe try loading the file again if the value is null? Idk...